# Align caption to the left of a centered figure

Tags: captions

Although searching for this topic brought up some results, none of them really worked for me.
I need to define a command to place an image horizontally centered to the page but that has its caption aligned to the left of the image.

I tried `minipage` with `\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}` what didn't work and currently I try to make use of the `\captionbox` which also doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% CAPTION STYLE
\DeclareCaptionFormat{labelstyle}{
    \setlength\fboxsep{2pt}
    \colorbox{blue}{{#1}}#2#3
} 
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{669933}

\newcommand{\midpict}[4]{    
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
                \captionsetup{format=labelstyle, justification=raggedright}
                \captionbox{#3\label{#4}}{\includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth]{#1}}
        \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
    \midpict{a.png}{0.5}{Caption}{fig:A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What should happen if the caption is loner than the width of the image?

Comment: `measuredfigure` from `threeparttable` might be of interest.

Comment: If the caption should be longer than the image, just overlap on the right side. I tried the `measuredfigure` already, with no success - but maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: How would a working example look like using `measuredfigure`?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way to solve this using  `minipage` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `singlelinecheck=false` to the caption settings.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% CAPTION STYLE
\DeclareCaptionFormat{labelstyle}{% <- needed
    \setlength\fboxsep{2pt}% <- needed
    \colorbox{blue}{{#1}}#2#3%
} 
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{669933}

\newcommand{\midpict}[4]{%
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
      \setcaptionwidth{#2\textwidth}
      \captionsetup{format=labelstyle,
        %justification=raggedright,% <- only needed if longer captions should not be justified
        singlelinecheck=false% <- added
      }
      \includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth]{#1}
      \caption{#3}\label{#4}
  \end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}
\midpict{example-image}{0.5}{Caption}{fig:A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Regarding a comment below: You can also use a `minipage` instead `\setcaptionwidth`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% CAPTION STYLE
\DeclareCaptionFormat{labelstyle}{% <- needed
    \setlength\fboxsep{2pt}% <- needed
    \colorbox{blue}{{#1}}#2#3%
} 
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{669933}

\newcommand{\midpict}[4]{%
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
      \captionsetup{format=labelstyle,
        %justification=raggedright,% <- only needed if longer captions should not be justified
        singlelinecheck=false% <- added
      }
      \begin{minipage}{#2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}
      \caption{#3}\label{#4}
      \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}
\midpict{example-image}{0.5}{Caption}{fig:A}
\end{document}
```

Maybe you do not need package `float`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% CAPTION STYLE
\DeclareCaptionFormat{labelstyle}{% <- needed
    \setlength\fboxsep{2pt}% <- needed
    \colorbox{blue}{{#1}}#2#3%
} 
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{669933}

\newcommand{\midpict}[4]{%
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{#2\textwidth}
        \captionsetup{format=labelstyle,
          %justification=raggedright,% <- only needed if longer captions should not be justified
          singlelinecheck=false% <- added
        }
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}
      \captionof{figure}{#3}\label{#4}
      \end{minipage}
  \end{center}%
}

\begin{document}
\midpict{example-image}{0.5}{Caption}{fig:A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Appreciated, thanks! So there's no easy solution using minipages? I just try to keep the amount of used packages at a minimum.

Comment: @po.pe I did not use an additional package. You have already used package `caption` to change the layout of the figure label. Package `caption` also provides `\setcaptionwidth`. But I have removed package `subcaption` from the MWE - its not needed in my example.

Comment: @po.pe I have added an example using a `minipage` and an additional example without package `float`.

Comment: Yeah sorry I was somehow mixing things up,... my fault. Thanks for the clarification and the additional effort. Would give another +1 if I could